# Power query / Excel transpose restructure data data

Tags: excel, powerquery, transpose, data-wrangling, m

This is the updated question: I like to change a table looking like this

[image]

into a table looking like this:

[image]

how can I do this?

Because I cannot handle programming language very well. Can anyone show me how do this with the menu bar?

Best regards
wbart

Comment: I can't follow the links to your images but have you tried the Transpose capability of Power Query?

Comment: Transpose won't achieve the desired result

Comment: Did any of these answers help at all? If so, please upvote that answer and then accept it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powerquery, paste into home ... advanced editor...

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"name", "Symbol"}, {{"data", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([value], Text.From), ","), type text}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Symbol", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Sorted Rows", List.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows"[Symbol]), "Symbol", "data")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Beat me by 7 seconds lol. Have an upvote.

Comment: nothing else going on around here! you were shorter but I sorted!

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the sort.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"name", type text}, {"Symbol", type text}, {"value", type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Symbol]), "Symbol", "value", each Text.Combine(_, ","))
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```